# Can you map Enums to Reference Tables Using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, enums

Is there a way to specify that an Enum defined in an entity framework class maps to a reference table in the database?

For example if I have an enum called color with values Red, Blue and Green can I map it automatically to a joined reference table with an integer primary key and a varchar color column?

Comment: not that im aware of no. Im Curious as to why that would be useful?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this can't be done. Can you explain what you are trying to acheive with that. Maybe another solution to your problem could be provided

Comment: We have a database that is structured to use reference tables to ensure that values in a property come from a defined set of values. We would like to mirror this in our entity framework model (and expose it with OData)